# stdin doesn't work after I read from redirection

Tags: stdin, io-redirection, recv, fgetc

Basically, my program is able to read the input from the redirection until the end of file. However, when I'm trying to read one more time from stdin, the program only reads the end of file character and skips to the next part of my program. I've been trying to figure out how to reset or clean stdin, but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate input (haha, that's a pun) on this question. Thanks!

Edit 1:

Code:

```
              while( fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)  ){
            printf("%s", buf);
            if(strcmp(buf,"\n") == 0){
              break;
            }
            while(write(right_con, buf,sizeof(buf)) < 0) {
              printf("Error writing to socket\n");
              exit(1);
            }
            memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
          }
          rc = read(keyboard,buf,sizeof(buf));
```

Yeah, so this code has a while loop that first tries to read from redirection and then sends it to a socket. (That part works fine) My biggest problem is that after if finished to read the file using that loop for redirection, it skips the read(keyboard, buf,sizeof(buf)). Thanks again. Let me know if those are enough details.

Comment: Add your best attempt. It's hard to correct code by descriptions.

Comment: Yeah, I just added some code sample.